# Add items to array without refreshing the page?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms

http://alpha.ripfy.com/

As seen in the following demo, I have a YouTube video that I want to be able to play while adding items to the array in PHP. Sadly, this isn't possible from what I've tried because the page refreshes every time I add an item to the array.

Would there be any way of achieving this without the page refreshing (forcing the video to restart?)

**Code:**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['playlist'])) {
        $playlist = $_POST['playlist'];
    } else { // Else set my default list
        $playlist = array("Be more.mp3", "Drift Away.mp3", "Panda Sneeze.mp3");
    }

    if (isset($_POST['name1'])) {
        $playlist[] = $_POST['name1'];
    }
?>

<form method="post">

<?php
    foreach($playlist as $song) {  
?>

<input type="hidden" name="playlist[]" value="<?php echo $song?>">

<?php
    }
?>

<input type="text" name="name1"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit1"/>
</form>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pzB6CxChIQk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<?php
    foreach ($playlist as $value) {
        echo $value."<br>";
    }
?>
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: aren't you getting any errors? you din't put a semicolon in <?php echo $song **;** ?>

Comment: No, no errors - the demo works as intended, but thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: PHP displays content on the page when the page loads (or with ajax content). When the page is loaded already, I don't see the benefit of adding to a PHP array. Maybe what you actually want to do is display an additional input on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my answer. That fully works. In this script, the server checks the presence of a name1 request (post or get). If exists, it returns the string posted (only) and if doesn't, it returns what already was there. And the post() method posts (gets) the data and appends to the container using `innerHTML+= data + "<br>";`
evaluate the code, it should be self explanatory.

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['playlist'])) {
    $playlist = $_REQUEST['playlist'];
} else { // Else set my default list
    $playlist = array("Be more.mp3", "Drift Away.mp3", "Panda Sneeze.mp3");
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['name1'])) {
   // if exists, return plain text responce. NOT HTML
    $playlist[] = $_REQUEST['name1'];
    echo $_REQUEST['name1'];
}
else{

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script>
text= ""

function onUpdate(){
    text = document.getElementById("name1").value;
}

function handler(data){
     document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += data+"<br>";
}

function post(){
    onUpdate();
    $.get("index.php", name1="+text, handler);
 }
</script>

<input type="text" name="name1" id="name1"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit1" onclick="post()"/>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pzB6CxChIQk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<br>
<div id="container">
<?php
    foreach ($playlist as $value) {
        echo $value."<br>";
    }
?>
</div>
</body>
<?php  };?>
```

Although, it works as intended, i don't see the point of using it. just plain js should work

Answer (score 2):

if you need that these information be storaged in database or anything on server sider don't use the convencional form post, use AJAX with JQuery.

First create a div(container)to render the list content where you need the information apears:

```
<div id="list_musics"></div>
```

Then create a page(i.e. page.ajax.php) that will treat your request. If you need you can put the information in a database or anything you want by this page. This page must return the content you want to render.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="ajaxcaller">
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('#ajaxcaller').on('click', function(){
    //AJAX CALL WITH POST METHOD
    var text = $('input[name=name1]').val();
    $.post(page.ajax.php,text,function(data){
        //Render your content in the container created on HTML
        $("#list_musics").html(data);
    });
});
```

If you just need to show what you wrote on text input instead of storage or treat the information, you may just use JQUERY to render the information in the container you created.

```
$('#ajaxcaller').on('click', function(){
    //AJAX CALL WITH POST METHOD
    var text = $('input[name=name1]').val();
    // PUT THE TEXT RIGHT AFTER THE CONTENT THAT ALREADY EXISTS IN THE CONTAINER
    $("#list_musics").append(text);
});
```

Take a look here to see the sencond option:

https://jsfiddle.net/wqLf65ox/

Answer (score 0):

You have to send your form using `Ajax`, eg. via [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method.

After that you have to reload your container with list or add new item there with `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the $.post and $.get JQuery methods. One method might be to $.post back to a .php page that renders a container of html, then use $.get to retrieve just that html container and insert into the DOM.